Calculating relative risk or risk ratio with zero events/incidence
I was reading through this recent review on the effects of masking and came across this figure and table which displays risk ratios for the wearing of medical masks and no masks as measured by different outcomes in various studies.
Modulo some rounding issues, I can replicate the point estimate for the risk ratio on the far right column in the figure. E.g. The third row corresponding to the Aiello(PCR-influenza),2010 RR value of 2.43 is calculated from doing $\frac{5}{378}/\frac{3}{552}$.
But -- not being familiar with standard practice in biostatistics -- I am not sure what one does when 0 (zero) events are measured, such as in the second (Macintyer(PCR-influenza),2009) and seventh (Bundgaard(PCR-SARS-CoV-2),2002) rows of the figure.
The most useful source of information I can find online is this page from the NIH: Estimating Relative Risk When Observing Zero Events—Frequentist Inference and Bayesian Credibility Intervals - PMC.
There's a discussion here of three methods:

Adding one to each cell in the cross table.
Moving one non-event to event in the intervention group.
Adding 0.5 to each cell in the cross table.

As I understand it, the data presented here aren't in the standard cross table format (i.e. events and non-events for intervention and control groups), but playing around I found that method 3. (or my interpretation of it) seems to be the one used in the figure.
For Macintyre(PCR_influenza),2009, we get
$$ \frac{1 + 0.5}{94 + 0.5} / \frac{0 + 0.5}{100 + 0.5} = 3.19 $$
and for Bundgaard(PCR-SARS-CoV-2),2021, we get
$$ \frac{0 + 0.5}{2392 + 0.5} / \frac{5 + 0.5}{2470 + 0.5} = 0.09 $$
which match the corresponding entries on the right-most columns.
Q: Is this the correct procedure?
Certainly the first case seems to indicate so as it's hard to get a ratio anywhere close to 3 otherwise. But the denominators (the total number of observations in both the masked and unmasked cases) seem large enough that there is some room to fudge things. What happens when there are fewer than 10 total observations in both the intervention and control groups?
What is the statistical justification for this method?
